# Как могу добавить font-face с .ttf (scss)

Tags: html, css, scss

Пытался добавить файл.ttf и связывать с ним. Результат "sans-serif", а не "Karla, sans-serif"

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Karla';
    src: url("app/fonts/karla/Karla-Regular.ttf")
}

p {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не поможет ли, если добавить `format("truetype")` после `url("…ttf")`?

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Karla';
    src: url("app/fonts/karla/Karla-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Кстати, можете воспользоваться сервисом вроде [этого](https://www.web-font-generator.com/), сгенерирует валидный CSS и заодно сконвертирует шрифт в иные форматы для различных браузеров.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, я всегда так подключаю.

Возможно у вас не правильно указан путь к шрифту (точкой "отправления" является сам файл css)?

Например у меня шрифт подключается так:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('../fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf');
}
```

Структура расположения файлов такая:

```
/css/style.css
/fonts/PT_Sans-Web-Regular.ttf
/index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно необходимо просто поставить точку с запятой `;`

```
src: url("app/fonts/karla/Karla-Regular.ttf")
```

Comment: Да вроде нет...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?